# Using snake case without explicit Configuration dependency in Circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

As specified in the [documentation](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html) it is possible to convert snake case to a camel case that is idiomatic in Scala. I tried it and *it worked fine*. Here is it:

```
implicit lazy val configuration: Configuration = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames
@ConfiguredJsonCodec final case class ModelClass(someField1: String, someField2: Int, someField3: String)
```

I want to keep my model clean without adding dependencies on external frameworks so it comprises only business-specific case classes.

Is it possible to avoid addding the annotation `@ConfiguredJsonCodec` and bringing `implicit lazy val configuration: Configuration` into scope? Maybe it could be configured on the `Decoder` level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly possible. It's a trade off:

- if you have implicits in your companion objects, you don't have to import them
- if you don't want to have coupling with libraries in your models, you have to out all implicits in trait/object and then mixin/import them every single time you need them

If you are developing application with a fixed stack, chosen libraries for each task, and so on - having all implicits in companion is just cleaner and easier to maintain.

```
package com.example

package object domain {

  private[domain] implicit lazy val configuration: Configuration = ...
}
```

```
package com.example.domain

import io.circe.generic.extra._

@ConfiguredJsonCodec
final case class ModelClass(...)
```

Many utilities are optimized for this e.g. enumeratum-circe uses a mixin to add add codec for enumeration into companion object.

If you don't want to have them there, because e.g. you have your models in one module and it should be dependency-free, then you would have to put these implicits somewhere else. And that requires writing code manually, no way around it:

```
package com.example.domain

final case class ModelClass(...)
```

```
package com.example.domain.circe

import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.extra.semiauto._

// if I want a mixin:
//   class SomeClass extends Codecs { ... }
trait Codecs {

  protected implicit lazy val configuration: Configuration = ...

  implicit val modelClassDecoder: Decoder[ModelClass] = deriveConfiguredDecoder[ModelClass]
  implicit val modelClassEncoder: Encoder[ModelClass] = deriveConfiguredEncoder[ModelClass]
}

// if I want an import:
//   import com.example.domain.circe.Codecs._
object Circe extends Circe
```

If you pick this way, you are giving up on e.g. enumeraturm-circe's ability to provide codecs, and you will have to write them manually.

You have to pick one of these depending on your use case, but you cannot have the benefits of both at once: either you give up on boilerplate-reduction or on dependency-reduction.